# my mum is withholding my passport from my dad

Tags: united-kingdom

I'm 14 years old with a UK passport. In August, i am planning to go and live with my dad permanently. My mum says that she will not give my dad my passport when I go. Is this legal? My dad wants to take my abroad on holidays and I cant do this without my passport. I have already asked her to give it to him several times but she just gets angry.Please help

Comment: You say that you are planning to go and live with your dad permanently. Do you know the legal situation regarding this move (i.e. are you deciding this on your own, is there a legal divorce proceedings with your dad gaining custody of you, etc)? Note that if you can wait till you are 16, you can easily get a replacement passport https://www.gov.uk/renew-adult-passport/overview

Answer (score 2):

Tell your dad to see a lawyer.

If you want to live with your father permanently, you must tell your dad this and tell your dad to see a lawyer, and the lawyer may tell him to call CPS or take some other step.

Don't trust any advice you see here, this isn't a site for giving advice anyway (sorry, but that's how it is). There are professionals who know exactly what they are doing. Unfortunately there is very little you can yourself do, since you are so young.

Please, see tell your father to see a lawyer, and you will hopefully be able to find some sort of solution

Comment: You can also go and talk to the Citizens Advice Bureau. They give free legal advice, although you will probably have to queue a lot. Having said that, they'll probably tell you the same thing as here.

Answer (score 1):

The route is detailed by the [UK government](https://www.cafcass.gov.uk/grown-ups/professionals/child-arrangements-orders.aspx). The existing answer correctly notes that the father needs to make the request.

"In private law cases the child is not a party to the proceedings unless there are particular circumstances that make the case complex. ... Certain categories of people are entitled to make an application for a child arrangements order ...
1. The parent, guardian or special guardian of a child;"

Does your opinion count? Yes:

"Among the things the court must consider are: a) The ascertainable wishes and feelings of the child concerned (considered in light of his age and understanding);". Clearly there's a difference between a child of 14 months and 14 years. You've got a clear wish (live with dad), can see logical relations (holiday/passport) and express feelings (Mum angry). The judge will need to take that into account. However, he'll also need to take into account all those other factors that might matter, including those you might not even be aware of.

But this only matters if there's a court case. And your dad can't just start a court case - he'll need to check with a mediator first. The mediator will try to sort out the things with your mum&dad outside the court. And the mediator will probably end up asking you the same things as the judge would have to. If this mediation doesn't work, your dad is then allowed to file a court case.